# MVVM - DependencyProperty - Binding a String to Textbox - PropertyChanged event only fired up if mouse clicks on another element

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I am just playing with my first MVVM apps..

And found a crazy behavior, did not know how to solve it.

When i start my test app, the button is enabled.

Now click in the Textbox, delete the Text in it..

Button still enabled. Click anywhere else, nothing changes..

Click on the button, button changes to disabled cause canExecute is false !

Click in the Textbox and enter some text, Button still disabled..

In this case the button will never come back enabled cause i cannot click on an other element??!

here the **XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="tests.View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:tests"
    Title="View" Height="109" Width="156"
    >
<Grid>
    <Button
        x:Name="btn"
        Content="refresh"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="10,10,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="75"
        Command="{Binding RefreshCmd}" />
    <TextBox
        x:Name="txtbox_one"
        Text="{Binding testString}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="23"
        Margin="10,37,0,0"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="120"/>
</Grid>
```

here the **code**:

```
namespace tests
{
    public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public String testString
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(testStringProperty); }
            set { SetValue(testStringProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty testStringProperty=
            DependencyProperty.Register("testString", typeof(String), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata("HUHU"));


        public ViewModel ()
        {
            this.RefreshCmd=new RelayCommand(e => RefreshExec(), c => this.CanExecuteRefreshCmd());
        }

        public ICommand RefreshCmd { get; internal set; }

        private bool CanExecuteRefreshCmd ()
        {
            if (testString.isNotNullOrEmpty()) return true;
            return false;
        }

        int cnt=0;
        public void RefreshExec ()
        {
            testString=cnt++.ToString();
        }
    }

    public partial class View : Window
    {
        public View ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext=new ViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set binding's `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` :

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="txtbox_one"
    Text="{Binding testString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Height="23"
    Margin="10,37,0,0"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="120"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bindings that are TwoWay or OneWayToSource listen for changes in the target property and propagate them back to the source. This is known as updating the source. Usually, these updates happen whenever the target property changes. This is fine for check boxes and other simple controls, but it is usually not appropriate for text fields. Updating after every keystroke can diminish performance and it denies the user the usual opportunity to backspace and fix typing errors before committing to the new value. **Therefore, the default UpdateSourceTrigger value of the Text property is LostFocus and not PropertyChanged.**

**Since by default the [UpdateSourceATrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set to LostFocus for a TextBox, the command is executed only when you click the button**

Comment: thank you for this clear explanation ! in my opinion it should be the default.. but good to know! :)

Comment: You are Welcome. You can also use UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, or PropertyChanged (refer @har07 solution). For more info : see the MSDN Link mentioned in the post